# Deleted object is undefined in MEAN app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, postman

I am trying to build a MEAN stack SPA, and so far I have created the backend services using this tutorial: https://medium.com/netscape/mean-app-tutorial-with-angular-4-part-1-18691663ea96

Everything works fine when I am testing with Postman (POST, PUT, GET), however, when I try to delete an object, it results in the error:

```
{
 "status": 400,
 "message": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'n' of undefined"
}
```

Here is how my delete method looks in todos.service.js:

```
exports.deleteTodo = async function(id){

    try{
        var deleted = await ToDo.remove({_id: id})
        if(deleted.result.n === 0){
            throw Error("Todo Could not be deleted")
        }
        return deleted
    }catch(e){
        throw Error(e)
    }
}
```

and here is my todos.controller.js:

```
exports.removeTodo = async function(req, res, next){

    var id = req.params.id;

    try{
        var deleted = await TodoService.deleteTodo(id)
        return res.status(204).json({status:204, message: "Succesfully Todo Deleted"})
    }catch(e){
        return res.status(400).json({status: 400, message: e.message})
    }

}
```

When I try to delete an object, it successfully removes it (I can see it using robomongo that it has deleted it), however, I get the error message I wrote before. What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using Mongoose v5. The [remove](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-remove) method of the model doesn't require any parameters, and returns the deleted document.

In v4 [remove](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/api.html#model_Model.remove) just called collection's [remove](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#remove) method directly, and indeed requires the condition to delete and returns number of deleted documents.

Either limit version of mongoose in your `package.json` to something like `^4.0.0` or use a bit more modern tutorial.